# Camera permission without taking pictures & videos?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-permissions

I have made an AR(Augmented reality) app that just opens the camera without taking any pictures
and videos.

In my Mainfest, I used this permission for camera:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"></uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"></uses-feature>
<uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"></uses-feature>
```

However, when I uploaded in google play, it says

> HARDWARE CONTROLS
>   TAKE PICTURES AND VIDEOS
>   Allows the app to take pictures and videos with the camera. This permission allows the app to use the camera at any time without your confirmation.

In fact, my App DOES NOT take pictures and videos. It is just opening a camera and view
information on it without the ability of taking pictures and videos.

**My question is how do i modify my permission to just use the camera without taking pictures and videos ?**

Regards

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's 'Augmented Reality' (fixed it for you, after your affirmation)

Comment: Well, Google Play says your app is **allowed** to take pctures and capture videos, not that it actually does. Even though you may not be recording the video data to some persistent medium, in a way you're still capturing a video, just a 'live' one without the ability to play back. I guess the first sentence is all about semantics, but the second one is pretty clear: *"This permission allows the app to use the camera at any time without your confirmation."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Once you've asked for permission to use the camera API, there's no honor system for how you plan on using it. If you have access to the camera, you have access to the data stream which means you can capture photos and videos whether you do it through the documented methods or not. There's no way to give you access to this stream and force you not to capture it, hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do something when you specify camera features in the manifest by including the `android:required` attribute, and setting it to `false`

Check out: [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest)

Comment: I only have 5 features on the camera. Check here:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features